# Background image is not added through javascript

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I am trying to use modernizr so I javascript can detect if the browser supports `object-fit` and `object-position`. The code I got from modernizr works fine, but if it detects something like `no-object-fit` I want to execute this bit of code:

```
if (!Modernizr.objectfit) {
    $('.wrapper__figure').each(function() {
        var $container = $(this),
            imgUrl = $container.find('img').prop('src');
        if (imgUrl) {
            $container
                .css('background-image', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')');
        }
    });
}
```

I don't seem to get this working. No changes are made inside of the browser if I check in developer mode(I am only testing this in IE. All the other browsers don't need this). I think that it has something to do with adding `.css('background-image', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')');` to the `$container`, but I am not realy sure if this is the case or something else

Answer (score 1):

Its `attr` not `prop` - because `src` is an attribute, not a property.

```
if (Modernizr.objectfit) {
    $('.wrapper__figure').each(function() {
        var $container = $(this),
            imgUrl = $container.find('img').attr('src');

        if (imgUrl) {
            $container.css('background-image', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for pointing out to use attr instead of prop. Implementing this bit of code still didn't change anything.

Comment: But this code is correct so far and works. So maybe you need to tell us more about your issue, because for now I see no reason why this will not work.

Comment: I put a breakpoint in at the start of the function. Next I refreshed the browser and found out that the var $container is the body and not the class I want get.